# WCF + SSL no endpoint found

Tags: wcf, web-services, ssl

I'm figthing for hours now to figure out this problem.

I have a wcf service that I host on II7, all works fine when I use the normal http protocol.

I added SSL capabilites and since then I cannot access it from code. I can create a client but cannot run any of its methods.

here is what I have

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttp0">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport realm ="" clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://serverName.domname.local/WCFTest/MyWebServicec.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttp0" contract="SSLWebService.IMyWebService"
            name="WSEP">
            <identity>
                <dns value="serverName.domname.local" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I added a service reference to my project

and I use it like that

```
Dim client As MyWebServiceClient = New MyWebServiceClient()
Try
    client.GetDocumentByDocID(5)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

and here is what I get

> There was no endpoint listening at https://serverName.domname.local/WCFTest/MyWebService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Can anyone help me on this? I really do not understand what is going on...

note: I can access the webservice correctly using Internet Explorer (so I guess my certificate is ok)

Comment: it may be helpful to see the server configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right about that,

Sg wrong on the server side.

here is how I made it working

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType ="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="App_WcfWebService.AppWebServiceBehavior" name="App_WcfWebService.AppWebService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration ="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="App_WcfWebService.IAppWebService">

            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="App_WcfWebService.AppWebServiceBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="90" />                    
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the server web.config might be the faulty one here. I've got WCF over SSL work with the following app.config on client side.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport realm ="" clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>

      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://mycomputer/Service/Service.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
          contract="ServiceProxy.IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="mycomputer" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The only visible difference is ClientCredentialType which I have set to Windows as I want to use integrated windows authentication. The server web.config includes the following lines to setup the service which the client can consume.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WindowsBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Service.Service1Behavior"
               name="Service.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WindowsBinding"
                  contract="ServiceInterface.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="mycomputer" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Could you compare this to your web.config on the server side and see what differs? Or add your web.config to the question.